# SSH key passphrase

Tags: terminal, ssh-keys

I'm trying to get an SSH key on my mac, but after trying a couple of times I'm stuck when it comes to type passphrase. I cannot type anything.
I'm stuck at the key symbol shown in the picture:

[image: pic]

Comment: Your E-Mail adress ends with .com.com

Comment: Wrong place for this. Try SuperUser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Passphrase is hidden, but you can still write it. Just write the passphrase you want and hit ENTER
This key symbol means you have to enter the password and anything you type is hidden for security reasons.